# Different options for XmlSerialization and derived type

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have the following object graph:

```
public class BaseType
{
}

public class DerivedType : BaseType
{
}
```

When I pass DerivedType to XmlSerializer I need to have it reflect on BaseType instead of DerivedType. Is there a way to control this with attributes without implementing IXmlSerializer on DerivedType?

Comment: so you only want the properties of the BaseType and not of the DerivedType?

Comment: yes. that is correct. basically our in house orm serializers basetype, but i want to have a derived type in my domain for behavior and such. I'm not adding more properties, only behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have control over the serializer instancing, just pass a Type[] with the derived type object as extraTypes. Otherwise, add an

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Derived))]
```

to the base class definition. The output XML will look exactly the same as if you'd passed a base instance except the xsi:type attribute with the derived type name.

I think this is what you were asking for...